# Ошибка при изменении textView

Tags: java, android

```
TextView text1;
```

Oncreate:

```
text1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

public void Result(String string){
    text1.setText(string);
}

protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    if(resultString != null) {
        Log.d("Log",resultString.toString());
        Result(resultString.toString());
    }

}
```

При выполнении Result() выводится ошибка

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
```

`Log.d` успешно выдает строку.
Через `Oncreate` успешно изменяется textview

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        text1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        text1.setText("Ваше кодовое слово появится здесь");
    }

    public void Result(String string){
        Log.d("Log",string.toString());
        String Text = string.toString();
        text1.setText(Text);
    }
```

Методом эксперимента выяснил что проблема в функции `Result()`, так как она ни только не может устанавливать текст, но и читать, и т.д., будто у нее нет доступа

Comment: а где и как у вас `AsyncTask` создаётся?

Comment: @Serodv `class SendData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {`
В этом же файле

Comment: добавьте вывод строки в лог перед `text1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);` и проверьте - не выводится ли он после строки в логи из Result... возможен вариант что ваш `AsyncTask` выполняется раньше чем активность находит свои элементы (нам же не видно где вы его стартуете).

Comment: стартую при нажатии на кнопку, так что не думаю

Comment: Пока вы не покажете весь код класса, вам врядли удастся помочь.

Answer (score 3):

Попытка вызвать метод `setText()` на объекте, который ссылается на `null`. У вас `text1 == null`. Проверьте есть ли `R.id.textView` в разметке.

*ps: в java принято называть методы с маленькой буквы.*

Comment: Да, я уточнил в вопросе что через oncreate text1.setext() все спокойно меняется

Comment: Это сути не меняет у вас text1 == null. покажите весь код

Comment: весь код слишком много, скинул часть, что именно можно показать?

Comment: @МолюскаМоллюсков могу предположить, что вы где то два раза объявляете переменную text1

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/AKsPB7w.png