# Изменение textView через функцию

Tags: java, android

Есть `asynctask` в классе отличного от основного, к которому привязан `layout`,
Нужно вывести в `textView` результат (он является строкой)
Пытался сделать через функцию, которой передается строка, она берет данные и делает `setText`, но получаю ошибку при работе в этой функции, она будто не имеет доступа, потому что не работает ни `getText()`, не `setText()`
Как правильно реализовать мою задачу?

Comment: Приведите код вашего класса `AsyncTask`.

Comment: Не могу, все на теории, в `async` будет простой пост запрос а выводить надо будет строку состояния - `ok` или `false`

Comment: если вы пытаетесь в асинктаске что-то передать в textView то андроид такое запрещает. с интерфейсом можно работать только в UI потоке.

Comment: Уже во [втором вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/726291/%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-textview) об одном и том же вы вынуждаете участников гадать, что же у вас не так, отказываясь показывать код...

Comment: @eugeneek мне не нужно решение моей проблемы, я просто хочу узнать метод, которому можно передать строку, а он поменяет textView, не более

Comment: @МолюскаМоллюсков `TextView.setText` делает ровно то, что Вам нужно. Судя по ошибке в вашем предыдущем вопросе, Вы просто вызываете его в неправильном месте и/или в неправильное время, когда Ваш `TextView` ещё (или уже) не инициализирован.

Comment: @МолюскаМоллюсков Я правильно понимаю, что под "Есть asynctask в классе отличного от основного, к которому привязан layout" Вы имеете ввиду, что Ваш `TextView` находится в одной активити (или фрагменте), а Ваша `AsyncTask` в другом классе?

Comment: @Agrgg да, Вы абсолютно верно поняли, то есть метод делающий setText() вызывается из другого класса
Я кидал скрин кода, где показано, что в файле всего четыре использования textview, и там только одна инициализация
Вот он: https://i.imgur.com/AKsPB7w.png

Comment: передайте свой `text1` в конструктор асинктаска, запомните его там и делайте с ним что хотите, хоть дальше передавайте

Comment: @Serodv если не сложно - напишите код в ответ, одобрю, просто не совсем понимаю как это делать

Answer (score 1):

Вероятно, вы пытаетесь взаимодействовать с UI из метода `doInBackground()`, который исполняется в отдельном потоке.

Вам нужно перенести всю работу с UI в метод `onPostExecute()`, который как раз для этого и предназначен, он исполняется в UI потоке.

Comment: Я знаю чем различаются эти методы, и нет, я не пытался из бэкграунда взаимодействовать, все взаимодействия были из `onPostExecute`